# mod_wsgi with Django 500 error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4, Python 2.7.6, Django 1.9.5 and mod_wsgi 4.5.1 installed from source.

My folder structure looks like so:

```
project
 -site
   -mysite
      -apache
         -wsgi.py
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.append('/home/me/project/site')
sys.path.append('/home/me/project/site/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In my main /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file I have only edited the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/seb/project/funel/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
            <Directory "/home/seb/project/funel/mysite/apache">
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong? I seem to be getting a 500 Internal Server Error even though restarting Apache doesn't show any problems.

Comment: Where is your actual Apache site configuration then? (And anyway, on Ubuntu, you shouldn't be editing apache2.conf at all.)

Comment: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` Should I be loading the module in sites-enabled/000-default.conf?

Comment: No, you should be doing it by running a2enmod, but that is nothing to do with the problem. Please post the part of the Apache configuration where you actually configure your WSGI alias.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid, just edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound like your apache configuration is giving you most of the problems.  Please try to write to a log file from within wsgi.py file and determine if the server atleast uses the correct wsgi file.

For what it is worth I am attaching contents of a_django_site.conf  apache config file.  this file should be in /etc/apache2/sites-available  and should be enabled using sudo a2ensite a_django_site.conf thereafter reload and restart.

```
Define MY_IP=129.222.333.444
WSGIPythonPath  /home/your_name/.virtualenvs/venv_proj_name/bin/python:/home/your_name/.virtualenvs/venv_proj_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName {MY_IP}
ServerAlias http://{MY_IP}/

DocumentRoot /usr/local/src/proj_dir

Alias /static /usr/local/src/proj_dir/django_static/
Alias /images /usr/local/src/proj_dir/stock/media/
Alias /favicon.ico /usr/local/src/proj_dir/apache/favicon.png

WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/src/proj_dir/proj_name/wsgi.py

<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have no idea what I did wrong but I edited some of your code and it now works! You're a star! I spent hours on this!

Comment: It is also probably worth figuring out where your Apache logs are being written. They'll likely give you more detail than a 500, and are useful to include in questions like these. Good job getting it working.